# How do I define a trait with subtraits so their methods only take shared implementation?

Tags: scala

My meta-question would be "How do I ask this question intelligibly?" but perhaps an example would make it clearer:

```
trait Toolbox {
  trait Bolt
  trait Wrench {
    def tighten(b : Bolt) 
  }

  def getWrench : Wrench
  def getBolt : Bolt
}


object MetricToolbox extends Toolbox {
...
}

object EnglishToolbox extends Toolbox {
...
}
```

Of course, a metric wrench can only tighten a metric bolt; ditto for tools from the English toolbox.  My question is, how do I express that in a type-safe way so the following *won't* compile:

```
MetricToolbox.getWrench tighten EnglishToolbox.getBolt
```

but the following will:

```
def doTighten(box : Toolbox) = box.getWrench tighten box.getBolt
```

I know for a fact that this is possible because I heard Martin Odersky say it with his own mouth at the Scala meetup last night but at that moment, my wife called my cell and I had to scurry out of the room before he explained how.

**EDIT** didierd pointed out that my code worked as written.  He's right -- I'm a little unclear on the details but it does.  The natural reverse questions is, how do I *not* do that?  The answer was pretty simple:  put those classes at the same level as the main trait.

```
trait Nail
trait Hammer {
  def pound(n : Nail)
}

trait Toolbox {
  trait Bolt
  trait Wrench {
    def tighten(b : Bolt) 
  }

  def getWrench : Wrench
  def getBolt : Bolt
  def getNail : Nail
  def getHammer : Hammer
}

 MetricToolbox.getHammer pound EnglishToolbox.getNail // this DOES compile
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As written, it already works. As `Bolt` and `Wrench` are nested inside `Toolbox`, the `Bolt` that types the  argument of `tighten` means a `Bolt` of this exact toolbox, not a `Bolt` of any toolbox. They are written respectively `someToolbox.Bolt`, which means a `Bolt` of the exact instance `someToolBox` and `Toolbox#Bolt`, which means the `Bolt` defined in the type `Toolbox`, whatever the insatance toolbox. So `Toolbox#Bolt` is a common supertype of all `x.Bolt`.

Here `Bolt` without qualification means `this.Bolt`, `this` being the enclosing Toolbox. So you cannot mix.

Comment: Huh.  Now I'm thinking Odersky didn't explain at all, just pointed out that it worked.